# How to upload an image programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, image, upload

I am trying to simulate a file upload to a website. I have an html form like this:

```
<input name="upl" type="file" style="width:266px" value="File" id="file_input_box" onchange="AFUpload.ad_placement(this.form.upl, 5242880)">
```

or

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="StartUpload(this.form, this.form.file.value)" size="40" style="margin-top:5px;">
```

This open standard "open file dialog box", for uploading a file, in this case an image. I want to upload an image but not by clicking the button.

Is this close or just stupid?

```
void Set(string tagname, string attribute, string attName, string value)
        {

            HtmlElementCollection tagsCollection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tagname);

            foreach (HtmlElement currentTag in tagsCollection)
            {

                if (currentTag.GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(attName))

                    currentTag.SetAttribute("value", value);
            }
        }


Set("input", "name", "upl", @"C:\image.jpg");
```

Comment: Have you searched "uploading images in .net".  There are millions of results on how to do this.

Comment: @AliK A situation where you have too many choices is worse than having a few. Now seriously, I try but just can't do it. Could you suggest me any specific link?

Comment: Try [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET)